# Export data from model with reverse foreign key

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I'm trying to export a model 'Class' with all the models that are related.
Exporting the teacher's data with the ForeignKeyWidget worked. But how do I get the data (name, age) of all students into the export?

Models:

```
class Teacher(model.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Student(model.Model);
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Class = models.ForeignKey(Class)

class Class(model.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Level = PositiveIntegerField()
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
```

Admin:

```
class ClassResource(resources.ModelResource):
    Teacher_Name = fields.Field(
        column_name = 'Teacher',
        attribute = 'Teacher',
        widget = ForeignKeyWidget(Teacher, 'Teacher'))

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = {'Name', 'Level', 'Teacher_Name'}
```